# Hitachi Content Platform (HCP) S3 - How to I disable or delete previous versions?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am (unfortunately) using [Hitachi Content Platform](https://www.hitachivantara.com/en-us/products/storage-systems/file-object-storage/content-platform.html) for S3 object storage, and I need to sync around 400 images to a bucket every 2 minutes. The filenames are always the same, and the sync "updates" the original file with the latest image.

Originally, I was unable to overwrite existing files. Unlike other platforms, on HCP, you cannot update a file that already exists when versioning is disabled, [it returns a 409 and won't store the file](https://knowledge.hitachivantara.com/Documents/Storage/Content_Platform/9.0.x/Developer_documentation/Using_the_HCP_HSwift_API/06_Working_with_objects), so I've enabled versioning which allows the files to be overwritten.

The issue now is that HCP is set to retain old versions for 0 days for my bucket (which my S3 admin says should cause it to retain no versions) and "Keep deleted versions" is also disabled, but the bucket is still filling up with objects (400 files every 2 minutes = ~288K per day). It seems to cap out at this amount, after the first day it remains at 288K permanently (which seems like it's eventually removing the old versions after 1 day).

Here's an example script that simulates the problem:

```bash
# Generate 400 files with the current date/time in them
for i in $(seq -w 1 400); do
  echo $(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S') > "file_${i}.txt"
done

# Sync the current directory to the bucket
aws --endpoint-url $HCP_HOST s3 sync . s3://$HCP_BUCKET/

# Run this a few times to simulate the 2 minute upload cycle
```

The initial sync is very quick, and takes less than 5 seconds, but throughout the day it becomes slower and slower as the bucket begins to get more versions, eventually taking sometimes over 2 minutes to sync the files (which is bad since I need to sync the files every 2 minutes).

If I try to list the objects in the bucket after 1 day, only 400 files come back in the list, but it can take over 1 minute to return (which is why I need to add `--cli-read-timeout 0`):

```bash
# List all the files in the bucket
aws --endpoint-url $HCP_HOST s3 ls s3://$HCP_BUCKET/ --cli-read-timeout 0 --summarize                

# Output
Total Objects: 400
   Total Size: 400
```

I can also list and see all of the old unwanted versions:

```bash
# List object versions and parse output with jq
aws --endpoint-url $HCP_HOST s3api list-object-versions --bucket $HCP_BUCKET --cli-read-timeout 0 | jq -c '.Versions[] | {"key": .Key, "version_id": .VersionId, "latest": .IsLatest}'
```

Output:

```json
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107250810359745","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107250814851905","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107250827750849","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107250828383425","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251210538305","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251210707777","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251210872641","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251212449985","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251212455681","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251212464001","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251212470209","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251212644161","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251212651329","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251217133185","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251217138817","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251217145217","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251217150913","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251217156609","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251217163649","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251217331201","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251217343617","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251217413505","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251217422913","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251217428289","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251217433537","latest":false}
{"key":"file_001.txt","version_id":"107251344110849","latest":true}
// ...
```

I thought I could just run a job that cleans up the old versions on a regular basis, but I've tried to [delete the old versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/DeletingObjectVersions.html) and it fails with an error:

```bash
# Try deleting an old version for the file_001.txt key
aws --endpoint-url $HCP_HOST s3api delete-object --bucket $HCP_BUCKET --key "file_001.txt" --version-id 107250810359745

# Error
An error occurred (NotImplemented) when calling the DeleteObject operation:
Only the current version of an object can be deleted.
```

I've tested this using MinIO and AWS S3 and my use-case works perfectly fine on both of those platforms.

Is there anything I'm doing incorrectly, or is there a setting in HCP that I'm missing that could make it so I can overwrite objects on sync while retaining no previous versions? Alternatively, is there a way to manually delete the previous versions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like the below

```
aws s3api --endpoint-url $HCP_HOST --profile default delete-objects --bucket $HCP_BUCKET --delete "$(aws s3api --endpoint-url $HCP_HOST --profile default list-object-versions --bucket $HCP_BUCKET --query='{Objects: Versions[].{Key:Key,VersionId:VersionId}}')"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Sudhi, this doesn't work either. I've tried deleting versions but it also doesn't work. I actually met with Hitachi on this and what I'm trying to do is not possible. All objects and versions in HCP are immutable, and the only way to delete old versions is to let the garbage collection process clean them up after they have been marked for deletion. In my case, this means a minimum of 24 hours of versions will be stored, since that is the configured time for the garbage collection job for our HCP instance.

Answer (score 0):

there is and option in name space settings:

namespace > settings > Overwrite
and then check the box of:
Allow overwrite of objects via Hitachi API for Amazon S3 if versioning is disabled

this will allow you to do what you are looking for.

https://knowledge.hitachivantara.com/Documents/Storage/Content_Platform/9.6.x/Managing_a_Tenant_and_its_Namespaces/Managing_namespaces/03_Configuring_a_namespace

search in page "Allowing object overwrites"

Hope its help.